# iPhone 3GS no sim error

Tags: iphone, sim

I got an iPhone 3G from a friend and it is showing "no sim card" and I know the sim card is good and it won't let me do anything but phone start up. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Is the phone SIM locked?

Answer (score -1):

Restore that iPhone. If the problem persists: take it to a repair shop. It is probably a hardware problem. I had the same problem myself.